# Using dynamically limit in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, limit

I want to use

```
select * from table limit x;
```

This x can change dynamically. I don't want to use number. There are a solution for limit that use parameter?

Comment: Where does this limit come from? Is it calculated within postgresql?

Comment: It comes from database as a column

Comment: Can you give an exmple? Why do you store limits inside a column? How are they calculated?

Comment: I want to call table according to months. If its 31,30,29,28 etc. Program calculate months and I want to use it as limit. there is a way in postgresql for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. Never needed to myself but:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT (SELECT a_limit FROM other_table);
```

Obviously that sub-query should only return one row.

Comment: Yes it does. I ran it before posting.

Answer (score 0):

To further expand on Richard Huxton's answer, this could be used in a `LATERAL` sub-query, for example to dynamically limit a K-Nearest Neighbours query:

```
SELECT loc_id, num_neighbours, neighbour_id
FROM locations,
LATERAL (SELECT neighbour_id 
         FROM neighbours 
         ORDER BY ST_distance(locations.geom, neighbours.geom) 
         LIMIT num_neighbours) knn
```